# TS stating that test() is not a property on a string?

Tags: typescript

I have a simple **RegEx** pattern test that I'd like to run on a string; you can see this in the example below as the variable `part`.

[image: part is a string]

When I do this, however, the red-squiggly line is indicating the error of:

> Property 'test' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

I am using TS 3.2.2 and my `tsconfig.json` is rather unexciting:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es2017",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*-spec.ts"]
}
```

Can anyone help me understand this? Clearly `test` IS a property on string!

Comment: As the error says... [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is a method of `RegExp` and not `String`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put it on chrome console and you will get this:
[image]
but you can do this:

```
if( /\s+-\s+-[0-9]/.test(part) ) return part;
```

Comment: Wow that's embarrassing. I looked it up to be sure test did hang off string but then I didn't spend enough time on the example. Thanks for helping though.